# PHP not reading/writing emojis from MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've recently upgraded a server to ubuntu 22.04 LTS (from 20.4). This meant moving from PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.1. All works fine (following work on replacing from deprecated PHP functions).

However, I can no longer get PHP to read or write emoji characters into a mysql database field.

The database field in question is utf8mb4 with the correct collation. I can write the emojis into the mysql field using SQL directly (e.g. using dbeaver). But if I try the same using PHP I get the 'incorrect string value' error when writing, and just '???' in place of the emoji when reading from the field.

I read elsewhere that I may need to be using 'nd_mysqli' module instead of 'mysqlnd' module, but haven't been able to work out how to switch (if this is indeed the solution).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you put the code you use to write to the database in your question? Try to post only the minimal code needed to perform the write, but please test it, to see if it actually has the same problem, before you post it here. If we have the code we could try to reproduce the problem and that will make it a lot easier to come up with a solution. Code is king.

Comment: Alternatively you could read through this Q&A: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).